# How to use a UISplitViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

So I add a `UISplitViewController` to a project which is embedded with a `UITabBarController`.

The `UISplitViewController` has a `UINavigationController` as a Master & Detail relationship with their own root controller.

The Master `UINavigationController` `rootController` has a detail segue to the Detail `UINavigationController`.

**See here:**

[image]

All pretty simple right ? Now in the TableViewController I do the following;

```
class TableViewController: TableViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

var collapseDetailViewController: Bool  = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    splitViewController?.delegate = self
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    collapseDetailViewController = false
}

// MARK: - UISplitViewControllerDelegate

func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

I aslo have a UISplitViewController extension and do the following;

```
extension UISplitViewController: UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

public override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
}  

}
```

With all this done I get the following problems;

- When tapping on `tableviewcell` to segue to detail view the detail view opens within the master left pane when on iPad in landscape instead of the right. I also cannot figure out how to show the Master View as the first view when in Portrait on iPad or on the iPhone. These two problems may or may not be related I am not sure.

  [image]
- On Mobile there is a bottom bar above the tab bar that I cannot figure out how to remove. I had the same problem on the iPad until I added the code in the `UISplitViewController` extensions `viewDidLoad` however that did not effect the mobile. See here,

[image]

PS: I am not sure if the question is too long, I felt it is best to put everything in context. Also I have been doing lots of research but I cannot find any resources in swift which use a UITabBarController.

I did follow the following tutorial http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so close just do the following.

Keep the split view layout with detail segues and return true for the following method and remove the rest of the code to do with the variable `collapseDetailViewController`.

```
func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
return true    
}
```

Put the following in you Master View controller

```
self.splitViewController!.delegate = self;

self.splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible

self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Add `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` to your detail view controller as mentioned by the previous answer. That should remove the bar appearing on your view controllers.

Also if you want some extra functionality add the following if you want your detail view to use the full screen on iPad.

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 2):

As for the splitViewController's master to be visible, you need to add this in splitViewController's ViewDidLoad. Else the master view controller is present as a side menu which you can drag in Portrait mode

```
self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
```

But, this master detail view will only be visible in iphone 6 plus and ipad only, otherwise ,it will act just like a navigation controller. As For pushing the viewController to navigation controller, you are trying to push a navigation controller to another navigation controller. I don't think it is recommended. Just move the segue from first view controller (where you input text) to second one(color view controller), instead of the second navigation controller. If you are interested to show the details in the right section for ipad and iphone6, and as a new page for other devices, you should not use this way, remove the push segue and use a delegate to pass information that data is changed and refresh UI.

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

Also, i don't think you might need a navigationController as the details page, just the colors viewController might be enough, if you are not interested in further navigation from the details page.

For detailed information on the behaviour of split view controller in iphone and iPad, just check https://www.raywenderlich.com/94443/uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Try adding `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` to your navigationController's viewDidLoad for the gap issue

Comment: So I have done everything you said, even looked at the raywenderlick tutorial (already done so before) and created a new project as a master detail to see how apple do it. All the examples have it so the detail view is shown first then you go back to the master - which makes no sense to me, for e.g look at the settings app you choose the category first not load general settings then go back to categories. The detail view still loads in the master window and now have two bottom bars :( the only code in the master atm is         `self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .Automatic`

Comment: then , don't show the detailViewController. Do it in masterViewController's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. What i did for my app was 2 storyboard for ipad and iphone, with and without splitViewController.

Comment: the action's in deatilVC's navigationbar should be set to splitVC's or master's

Comment: Remove `self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .Automatic` from your master View Controller

Comment: That was just a typo I was using .AllVisible

Comment: Use `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` for both your master and detail view controller.        Also use `self.splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible` instead of `self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible` check my answer.