# UISplitViewController Share same Header

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Im facing an issue that I don't know if it's possible to solve  I need to develop something that looks like this for iPhone, Ipad

iPad:
[image]

iPhone:
[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm confused on what you're asking... Do you need to know how to implement a SplitViewController? Or do you need help with making the header look a certain way based off the device orientation?

Comment: I need to share the same header between iPad and iPhone using the SplitViewController

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone the only way to get the SplitView to look like an iPad's is if the device is flipped sideways. It won't preserve the solid header on the Navigation Controller. There are a few topics [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705865/force-uisplitviewcontroller-to-always-show-master-only-in-landscape-on-iphone?noredirect=1&lq=1) and 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251897/how-to-use-a-uisplitviewcontroller-in-swift?rq=1) that might be able to help you a little more.

Theres some code indicated that might be what you are looking for to help you preserve the solid header, but as far as I know there's no way to do it on iPhone - at least in Portrait orientation. I'm thinking that this code might fix your problem, but I havent tested it yet...

Put the following in you Master View controller:

```
self.splitViewController!.delegate = self;

self.splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible

self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```